# I need overflow: hidden; in body tag but need that the scroll does not disappear

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

It is need that the scroll bar does not disappear with `overflow: hidden;` , because the content jumps. Are there any options to keep it visible other than styling it?

I found many answers on how to hide the scroll, but I need the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's work for you !!!

you just need to add style for `html` tag `overflow: scroll;` and for `body` tag `overflow: hidden;` like ...

```
html{overflow: scroll;}
body{overflow: hidden;}
```